# How to upgrade .net framework 4.5 to .net framework 4.6?

Tags: .net, frameworks

I have existing .Net project. The project targeting .net framework 4.6. But i have .net framework 4.5 version in my machine. I downloaded 4.6 version and installed then restarted . Now the project not loading. Please suggest your solution.

Comment: Installing 4.6 is not enough.  Google ".net 4.6.2 developer pack".

Comment: Yes, that also i installed. But the project shows unavailable error

Comment: Be sure to post as little info as possible, always better when somebody has to write a manual to help you.  "unavailable error" is too much info, I recommend you delete that.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue because I was trying to install a nuget package which requires the 4.6.1 version at least (Mine was 4.5.2), so I right clicked to the project and selected the  properties option and change the Target Framework as shown in the image and that was enough! Keep in mind that you have to install previously the Net. Framework you are trying to upgrade.

[image: change the framework version]

Comment: By the way be aware to upgrade your installed nuget packages as needed.

Answer (score 1):

To migrate on next version of .net framework require changes to your code.In case, your app doesn't have to be migrated, you can run it in the .NET Framework 4.5 or later versions without recompiling it. for more help visit :[Migration Guide to the .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657133(v=vs.110).aspx)